# C# Insert data to dabase not working

Tags: c#, database, insert

can you tell me why this code is not inserting anything in my database? I have some troubles, I'm new.
[image]

```
 private void reserveButton()
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Rezervari VALUES (@nume, @rand, @coloana, @data, @film, @tipBilet)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rand", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coloana", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", listBox2.SelectedValue);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@film", listBox1.SelectedValue);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipBilet", listBox4.SelectedValue);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Ticket Reserved. See you at the movies!");
    }
```

Comment: Please post code and not pictures

Comment: You're not opening the connection and not executing the query

Comment: What @GiladGreen said. Also, the answer is you never execute the command.

Comment: you need connection.Open(), and use adapter.ExecuteNonQuery() or the method that better suits your case

Comment: Ok. Now i put connection.Open and command.ExecuteNonQuery in the code and I've got this error on command.ExecuteNonQuery: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll   .. I edited the post and added the code

Comment: Can you post the whole error message

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string query = "INSERT INTO Rezervari (ColumnName1,ColumnName2) 
                                 VALUES (@ColumnName1,@ColumnName2)";         
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName1", "aaaa");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName2", "bbbb");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    }
```

Instead of ColumnName1 please write your Column Name

Comment: Thank you! I get no error from this but still it does not insert anything in my table.